Using Frobenius Coin problem, find the largest positive integer for which $8x+15y+20z=n$ has no solutions in the set of non-negative integers.
Using Frobenius Coin problem, find the largest positive integer for which  $8x+15y+20z=n$ has no solutions in the set of non-negative integers.
Frobenius Coin problem: If  $a,b$  are positive integers that are relatively prime $( a,b)=1$, the largest positive integer that cannot be written as a non-negative linear combination of $a,b$ like $ax+by$, $x,y\geq 0$ is $N=ab-a-b$. i.e., all integer greater of equal to $N+1=(a-1)(b-1)$ can be expressed as $ax+by$, $x,y\geq 0$.
$8x+15y+20z=n \implies  8x+5t=n$, where $t=3y+4z$. As $gcd(3,4)=1$, $N+1=(3-1)(4-1)=6.$ So, $t$ can be $6$ or above 6.
Also, $8x+5t=n$ with $gcd(8,5)=1$, so $N+1=(8-1)(5-1)=28.$ So, $n$ can be $28$ or above $28$. But we have, $t$ can be $6$ or above 6. How to use this result to find the answer,
Which option is correct: $43, 57, 59,$ None of these.
Edited

The gap in the final step of your reasoning is that you can only apply the Frobenius Coin problem if your variables can take any non-negative values. In your case, as you have correctly noted yourself, $t\ge 6$, and you can achieve any such value by appropriate assignment of $(y,z)$ variables. Given that, let $t=s+6$ and observe that any solution in nonnegative $(x,s)$ variables can be mapped back into $(x,y,z)$ variables by solving $3y+4z=s+6$, which is possible because $s \ge 0 \Leftrightarrow t \ge 6$.
We now establish the smallest $n$ such that the equation $8x+5(s+6)=n$ does not have integer solutions. First, we rewrite it as $8x+5s=n-30$; this equation is amenable to the Frobenius coin problem, which tells us that the largest such value of the right-hand side, $(n-30)$, is equal to $8\times 5 - 8 - 5 = 27$. This reasoning yields the bound $n-30\le 27$, which is equivalent to $n\le 57$, so the answer to your question must be 57.

Okay. But in the last paragraph, instead of taking $N+1=(8-1)(5-1)=28$, you have considered $N=8\times 5 - 8 - 5 = 27$. In my case, $n-30\le 28\implies n=58$. What are the logics of the difference of our opinions? Please explain the step.

@user1942348 I take the largest RHS $N$ which does not admit natural solutions, which is what is asked in the question. On the other hand, $N+1$ is the smallest RHS that does admit natural solutions, which is suitable for the subproblem of choosing a lower bound on $t$ but not for answering the original question.

Noodling.  $8=4\times 2$ and $20=4\times 5$ and the For $5,2$ we can get any number over $3$ (because $2\times 5 -5-2=3$).  So we can get any multiple of $4$ over $12$ with the coins $8$ and $20$.
We can add $30=2\times 15$ to those multiples of $5$ to get all evens over $42$ ($44$ is a multiple of $4$ over $12$ so it can be done with $8$ and $20$ only, and $46=30 + 16$ so it can be done).  So can add $15$ to get all numbers greater than $57$. ($58$ is an even above $42$ and $59=44+15$ and $44$ is a even above $42$)
We can verify $57$ is not possible. It is odd so it requires at least one $15$ and is possible if and only if $42$ is possible.  $42$ is even but not divisible by $4$ so can't be done with just $8$ and $20$ so needs at least $2$ $15$s.  So $42$ is possible if an only if $12$ is.  Which it obviously isn't. (Of course, $12$ is possible with $8,20$ if and only if $3$ is possible with $2$ and $5$, and $3= 2\times 5-5-2$ is the solution to the coin problem with $5$ and $2$ if we want to be thorough.)
